# Is the usage _a chalk piece_ acceptable in modern English?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning, uncountable-nouns

Most teachers in  India say **chalk piece** or **a chalk piece** instead of **a piece of chalk**.

I know that chalk is uncountable and the correct usage is ***a piece of chalk***.

But I have read in certain books that **a chalk piece** is also acceptable.

I would like to know whether the use is found only in India or it is also found even in native English speaking countries?

Is the usage **a chalk piece** acceptable in modern English even in speech?

Comment: Hi, I don’t agree with the genera statement that “most teachers say **chalk piece** … instead of “a piece of chalk.”   Do you mean “most teachers” in your country?  As an American, I’ve never heard this phrase.  It is not idiomatic in U. S. English.

Comment: @whiskeychief.You might have understood from my question in the end that it was teachers in India.However, I will edit it.

Answer (score 2):

When I read "chalk piece", I had never heard it and guessed at a piece of art drawn in chalk.

I am British and I would say

> "I write on the blackboard with/using chalk"
>   "use the chalk"
>   "use the
>   red chalk" (or any other colour)
>   "I love drawing in chalk"

so chalk does not currently need any adjustment the word chalk unless you are explicitly talking about geography or gardening means writing chalk.

I say currently as kids no longer use blackboards/ chalk in school, so this might change in the next generation.

Answer (score -1):

Read [*attributive nouns*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/attributive) where nouns, in special cases, serve as an adjective.

Say, *football team player* where all are nouns.

In *a chalk piece*, *a* is applied to *piece* and not *chalk.*

All in all, *a chalk piece* is valid.

---

**Now, the question is edited, and so is my answer.**

In InE, it is very common and you hear it from almost all teachers *including* English trainers! As I said, it can be considered as a case of attributive noun and is for sure grammatical.

Nevertheless, as other native speakers stated here, it is not idiomatic in the US/UK English but I'm sure that the meaning is conveyed *undoubtedly.*

Comment: I agree that it's valid, but in the areas of the United States where I grew up, we always said "a piece of chalk." Of course nowadays it's all whiteboards or smart boards anyway!

Comment: We always said a 'piece of chalk' in Britain, too, or possibly a 'stick of chalk'. You could get a 'box of chalks' from the stationery store. Nobody ever said a 'chalk piece'. I am talking here about the cylindrical sticks of chalk used by teachers to write on blackboards.

Comment: in InE, it is said [that way](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=VPc7AAAAIAAJ&dq=%22chalk+piece%22&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=%22chalk+piece%22). @MichaelHarvey

Comment: @MaulikV The asker is asking about countries where English is spoken natively. A tiny percentage of people in India speak English natively, and no one would consider it an anglophone country in that regard. There's no reason to prefer the version used by native speakers in the US or UK if everyone uses *chalk piece* where you are, however. The same would be true if people surrounding you called it *piece chalk* or *a chalk* or *carrot* or whatever. But if you're communicating with native speakers of English, it'd be appropriate to use the version they understand.

Comment: @userr2684291 the beauty of English is that it adapts words from every dialect/register. That is why, [new Englishes](https://www.thoughtco.com/what-are-new-englishes-1691343) have evolved and accepted by even native speakers. And, OP talks about *modern English* which I think fairly accepts *a chalk piece.*

Comment: When people talk about English, they normally mean Standard English. Indian English for the most part (and for the majority of people) doesn't qualify. In modern English, i.e. Standard English spoken in modern times, it's not "acceptable" to use *a chalk piece*. It might be "acceptable" in your modern variety of non-standard English, nonetheless. It's "acceptable" in standard English to the same degree that *a chalk* is "acceptable", or *a carrot*, when used to refer to a piece of chalk.

Comment: @userr2684291 you mean *spoken English* (even by native speakers) is standard English where *keys* could be a singular word? Eh! :)

Comment: @MaulikV English is primarily a spoken language. Not sure what you're trying to say there, though (*keys* would normally be a plural noun).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98763/discussion-between-maulik-v-and-userr2684291).

Comment: *Chalk piece* is ***not*** idiomatic in either UK or US English. It's *grammatical*, but it would hardly ever be said or spoken. Since the question isn't tagged with `indian-english` (and explicitly states it's *not* asking about Indian English), the answer to *Is it found in native English speaking countries?* is very rarely.

Comment: @userr2684291 For your information and others [**English is one of the 22 official languages recognized by the Constitution of India. "Soon,"** according to Michael J. Toolan, **"there may be more native speakers of English in India than in the UK,** a cohort speaking a new New English second in size only to the old New English spoken in America"](https://www.thoughtco.com/indian-english-inde-1691056)

Comment: @JasonBassford  As for the user not tagging a question Indian-English, you know very well that the OP (JVC) is Indian, we all know he's a new contributor, we can see it by his rep. It is possible, is it not, that he was unaware that such a tag existed.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Unless something extraordinary happened in the last 8 years, there's about 0.2 million native speakers of Standard IndE in India and elsewhere: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_English.

Comment: @Mari-LouA From the question: "I would like to know whether the use is found only in India."

Comment: @userr2684291 (edited) that same link says that 80 million claim English as their second language, which means that IndE is a reality, and has earned the right to be called an English dialect.

Comment: @Mari-LouA And for ~all those speakers it's a **non-standard** dialect of Indian English. The question is asking about native speakers of English (actually countries where English is spoken natively, which again, I wouldn't consider India as such, but we can generalize further). Does anyone know who these 200k Indians are? Given that, I'd venture a guess that no one here (including the answerer) is talking about the standard variety. Again, see my first few comments: I'm absolutely all *for* using such phrases *where appropriate*.

Comment: By the way, it hasn't "earned a right to be called an English dialect" just because there's a lot of people speaking it (there's hundreds of millions of people speaking English non-natively, including me), but [it has earned a right to be called a separate English dialect] because most of these people in India speak it in a specific way, using common vocabulary items not present in other dialects, or satisfying some such criteria.